# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. (NOT DUPLICATE)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Just upgraded to Angular 2.1. I have a @input value which I'm attempting to pass an array. As soon as I put *ngIf inside a template I get parse errors? If I print the input value I get: //[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. Why is this affecting *ngIf?

```
<div *ngIf="< my value "></div>
```

-- error
zone.js?fad3:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

Comment: Please add also the code of your `NgModule`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your module add

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
```

Comment: I have added commonmodule.. Still I am facing error. Its happening only in production bundle. Its working fine in locale

Comment: Also double-check if you were silly like me and named the module that contains common components `CommonModule` instead of the more...common `SharedModule`.