# "Cant bind to" error only shows up in production

Tags: angular, webpack, dev-to-production

Why am I getting "can't bind to... since it isn't a known property of ... error" in the production with Angular 4 + webpack?

The version of Angular is 4.1.3 and webpack version is 2.6.1. In my local there is no problem. Everything works well. In the production, I m uploading required files comes from "npm run build" to the weblogic. Then I m facing the errors like:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngclass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
>
> Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("i [blocked]=notifier.blocked [target]=pnl>   ] ngif="session && session.activeUser">

My dependencies:
[My dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36PXQ.jpg)

Webpack versions:[Webpack versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRedQ.jpg)

I have tried this: [Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828068/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div) and added browsermodule but still not working in prod.

There is no problem with typin:

```js
<div class="ui-grid" *ngIf="session && session.activeUser">
<model-dialog-component #modelDialog [contentFactory]='modelDialogContentFactory'></model-dialog-component>
<div class="ui-grid-row">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
        <div class='headers'>
            <div class='header'>
                <div id='logo'>
                    <span routerLink='home'><img [src]='logoPath' /></span>
                    <div class='mobile-nav' [ngClass]="acln ? 'op':'hd'" (click)='mnav($event)'>
                        <i class='icon-menu'></i>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It's because you write them bad. ngif is `*ngIf`, ngclass is `[ngClass]`. Mind how you write it, it's very important.

Comment: Can you edit your question with how you use these directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved issue by making **minimize=false** in the webpack.prod.js. Like this:

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
            htmlLoader: {
                minimize: false
            }
        }
    }),
```