# (Ionic v4 + ionic-tooltips) -> Can’t bind to ‘ngIf’ since it isn’t a known property of ‘div’

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tooltip, ionic4

I’m trying to use the [ionic-tooltips](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-tooltips) module with Ionic v4. The module was installed with npm.

Creating a new blank project and following the installation steps from the module site I got some problems. First with some missing components that I was able to fix manually changing the imports of some files, just like in this [question](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-tooltips-example/issues/3).

After that I got this other error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="tooltipHtml; else txt" [innerHTML]="tooltipHtml"></div>
    <ng-template #txt>{{ text }}</ng-t"): ng:///TooltipsModule/TooltipBox.html@1:9
Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="tooltipHtml; else txt" [innerHTML]="tooltipHtml"></div>
    <ng-template #txt>{{ text }}</ng-t"): ng:///TooltipsModule/TooltipBox.html@1:9
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
    [ERROR ->]<div *ngIf="tooltipHtml; else txt" [innerHTML]="tooltipHtml"></div>
    <ng-template #txt>{{ text }}<"): ng:///TooltipsModule/TooltipBox.html@1:4
Property binding ngIfElse not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
    [ERROR ->]<div *ngIf="tooltipHtml; else txt" [innerHTML]="tooltipHtml"></div>
    <ng-template #txt>{{ text }}<"): ng:///TooltipsModule/TooltipBox.html@1:4
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="tooltipHtml; else txt" [innerHTML]="tooltipHtml"></div>
    <ng-template #txt>{{ text }}</ng-t"): ng:///TooltipsModule/TooltipBox.html@1:9
Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="tooltipHtml; else txt" [innerHTML]="tooltipHtml"></div>
    <ng-template #txt>{{ text }}</ng-t"): ng:///TooltipsModule/TooltipBox.html@1:9
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
    [ERROR ->]<div *ngIf="tooltipHtml; else txt" [innerHTML]="tooltipHtml"></div>
<ng-template #txt>{{ text }}<"): ng:///TooltipsModule/TooltipBox.html@1:4
```

After some searching I got some awnsers that converged to the same [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828694/7123439): **Import Ionic CommonModule to your main Module**. I did this, no success.

My **home.page.html**:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-button tooltip="I'm a tooltip below a button" positionV="bottom" arrow>
       Press me to see a tooltip
      </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**home.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { TooltipsModule } from 'ionic-tooltips';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    TooltipsModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

**app.module.ts** (where I lastly tried to import CommonModule):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If there is any missing info, please ask.

Comment: Can you please post `HTML` where you have added `if` and `else` block

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are asking me. Since this is a ionic blank test, the only html avaliable is the one that I already posted. Is the first code block named "home.page.html". There is no `if` and `else` block related to this.

Comment: Add ``TooltipsModule.forRoot()`` to your ``app.module.ts`` imports array

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not fixed this issue, but I was able to use tooltips with Ionic v4 using other library, [popperjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js/v/1.14.3) with the angular wrapper [ngx-popper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-popper).